# How can I open my project in DevC++ to edit its code?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hi there I am a beginner and I am learning C++ using IDE **DevC++**
Till now I was just creating simple files by choosing the source file in the upleft corner.
And it was easy to run them and edit them.
But now, for the first time, I have created a project in it. It was a graphics project; it ran well
But now I don't know how to open its code, so I can edit it and make it better.
Hope the problem is clear
Help needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is very unclear. Maybe some screenshots of what you are attempting to do, and your current layout would help.

Comment: Captain Giraffe it's very simple, I create a graphics project in Devc++ then I write some code in it then I run it everything goes well but when I close Devc++ the next day when I open my Devc++ I don't know how to open that project that I made yesterday.